# Different Display of CSS opacity in Safari Browser

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, safari

I'm working on a hybrid App for mobile devices in the Ionic-Framework.
I try to make some HTML span look transparent to a certain degree for a defined area.
The HTML and CSS works fine on every android device, but is displayed horribly useless on every Apple Device. Meaning the shady Opacity and the related HTML elements suddenly are displayed at complete different places in the view everytime. The Opacity sometimes effects the whole page. When I delete the related HTML from the view, everything is fine which leads me to the suspicion safari just can't interpret my code the way I want it to.

I suspect a safari bug or some safari quirk to be responsible for the strange display.

Here how it is correct and looks like on android devices: https://ibb.co/diNxxw
And here how its crashed on every iOS device: https://ibb.co/eNfZcw   https://ibb.co/jiPGqG

This is my HTML

```
<ion-item>
                <ion-label class="label-left-filler" [ngStyle]="{'width': avgRatings[speise.id]?.ratingAverage ? (((avgRatings[speise.id]?.ratingAverage | roundDecimal : avgRatings[speise.id]?.ratingAverage)-1) * (25+5) +13) +'px' : 0 +'px' }">
                </ion-label>
                <ion-label class="label-rating">
                  <span class="span-rating">
                    <span class="span-emojicon">
                      <mat-icon class="mat-icon-one">sentiment_very_dissatisfied</mat-icon>
                      <span class='mat-icon-spacer'></span>
                      <mat-icon class="mat-icon-two">sentiment_dissatisfied</mat-icon>
                      <span class='mat-icon-spacer'></span>
                      <mat-icon class="mat-icon-three">sentiment_neutral</mat-icon>
                      <span class='mat-icon-spacer'></span>
                      <mat-icon class="mat-icon-four">sentiment_satisfied</mat-icon>
                      <span class='mat-icosxn-spacer'></span>
                      <mat-icon class="mat-icon-five">sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                </ion-label>
                <ion-label class="label-right-filler" [ngStyle]="{'margin-left': avgRatings[speise.id]?.ratingAverage ? (avgRatings[speise.id]?.ratingAverage | roundDecimal : avgRatings[speise.id]?.ratingAverage) * (25+5) -3 +'px' : 0 +'px' }">
                </ion-label>
              </ion-item>
```

And this is my corresponding CSS

```
  .label-rating {
    position: fixed;
    padding-left: 15px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .label-left-filler {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    z-index: 2;
  }
  .label-right-filler {
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    z-index: 2;
  }
  .mat-icon-one {
    background: radial-gradient(
      red $mat-icon-radial-gradient-inner,
      white $mat-icon-radial-gradient-outer
    );
  }
  span > .mat-icon {
    font-size: $mat-icon-font-size;
    width: $mat-icon-width;
    height: $mat-icon-height;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-mask-size: cover;
  }
  h2 span.mat-icon-spacer {
    padding: 0 $mat-icon-spacer-padding;
    background: white;
  }
```

Answer (score 9):

To be more cross-browser friendly, you can use the opacity element, and increase compatibility using browser-specific settings.

```
opacity: 0.5; /* Standard compliant browsers */
   -moz-opacity: 0.5; /* Firefox and Mozilla browsers */
   -webkit-opacity: 0.5; /* WebKit browser e.g. Safari */
   filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
```

Comment: I tried your code and again: it works on android, but crashed the view on iOS. Unfortuantely no solution.

Comment: Maybe it is something in the Ionic Framework.  I have not used that, perhaps there is an option in their API or in the Creator that could help.  Have you only tested the app within Ionic, or have you also tested it independently?